# How do I correctly import the Prophet module?

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to install the FBProphet module on my MacOS 10.15.5 with Python 3.10.10.
After succesfully installing the package through pip I tried importing the module (`from prophet import Prophet`) but was struck with this error message:

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 2
      1 #Trying the FP Prophet model on the data
----> 2 from prophet import Prophet

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prophet/__init__.py:7
      1 # Copyright (c) 2017-present, Facebook, Inc.
      2 # All rights reserved.
      3 #
      4 # This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
      5 # LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
      6 # of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
----> 7 from prophet.forecaster import Prophet
      9 from pathlib import Path
     10 about = {}

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prophet/forecaster.py:19
     16 import pandas as pd
     17 from numpy.typing import NDArray
---> 19 from prophet.make_holidays import get_holiday_names, make_holidays_df
     20 from prophet.models import StanBackendEnum
     21 from prophet.plot import (plot, plot_components)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prophet/make_holidays.py:14
...
    175 self.entity_name = entity_path[-1]
    176 self.module_name = ".".join(entity_path[0:-1])
--> 178 super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)```

Does anyone understand why this happens and how to fix this?
````

Comment: Just opened a new Google Colab (which runs on `Python 3.10.11`) and did `%pip install prophet` and `from prophet import Prophet`, which worked fine. Can you tell us more about your environment?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Python environments but I believe I'm working in a locally installed Pythin 3.10.10 kernel for VSCode, does that help?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! I assume you're not using a [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment), would you mind setting one up and doing your project-specific installations in that venv? Over my python career I've had a ton of installation issues, which usually got resolved when I created specific environments.

Comment: I think something has been broken in Prophet. I rebuilt my image in Docker last Thursday and everything worked fine. I rebuilt it this morning and now I get the same error message.

Comment: install the library using %pip install prophet and try again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution form a chineese website:

```
pip install holidays==0.24
```

the 0.25 version makes the error append.

tested on:
ubuntu 22.04,
python 3.10.4,
pip 23.1.2,
prophet 1.1.2

opened issue: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/2432